# Magnific-popup gallery duplicate images when i use it with Owl-carousel

Tags: asp.net, owl-carousel, magnific-popup

i have developed aspx page 
on it i have image galley  using owl-carousel
now when i added magnific-popup plugin and used gallery option 
then i noticed when i click on image on carousel it get popup successfully but  images get duplicated (inside popup)

[Owl-Carousel gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEIR1.png)

[First popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZFOn.png)

[Duplicated Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhvm1.png)

my aspx code :

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvDesrtProgramGallery" ItemType="SharedKernel.Core.Model.ProgramPhoto" SelectMethod="lvDesrtProgramGallery_GetData">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="item">
        <a class="desert-safari-gallery" href="<%# Item.PhotoPath %>">
                  <img src="<%# Item.MediumPhotoPath %>" alt="" />
                            <div class="overlay">
                               <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>                                   </a>
      </div>
      </a>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
</div>
```

---

Js code

```
$('.desert-safari .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    dots: false,
    nav: true,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    autoplay: true,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-4x"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-4x"></i>'],
    onInitialized: callback,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1,
            nav: false,
            margin: 80
        },
        570: {
            items: 1,
            nav: false
        },
        768: {
            items: 2,
            nav: false
        },
        992: {
            items: 3,
            nav: false,
        },
        1200: {
            items: 3,
            nav: true,
            loop: false
        }
    }
});
function callback(event) {
    $(".desert-safari-gallery").magnificPopup({
        type: "image",
        removalDelay: 160,
        loop: false,
        preloader: false,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        showCloseBtn: false,
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this problem so I thought I'd give you my answer/solution.

**The Reason:**
Since your using owl carousel to loop, owl carousel is cloning items.  Because your cloning the items within your carousel you're now feeding duplicates into the popup gallery.  What a hassle right?  There are two seemingly obvious solutions.

**Solution 1:** Don't use owl-carousel's loop.

This may not be the preferred solution if you want the looping feature of your carousel but this will no longer cause the popup to receive duplicate entries.

**Solution 2:** Create an array of objects based on the resulting elements, remove the duplicates, then use magnific's items property to set the gallery items.

Here is a working script I had to create based off a similar scenario I'm sure you can dissect what the process is:

```
(function( $ ) {
            'use strict';

             $( window ).load(function(){

                 var GalleryItems = [];

                 $('.gallery img').each(function(i){

                     var src = $(this).attr('href');
                     var theSrc = { 
                        src: src,
                        type: 'image'
                      };
                     GalleryItems.push(theSrc);

                 });

                 var GalleryItems = GalleryItems.reduce(function(previous, current) {

                      var object = previous.filter(object => object.src === current.src);
                      if (object.length == 0) {
                        previous.push(current);
                      }
                      return previous;
                    }, []);

                 theGallery();

                 function theGallery(){
                     $('gallery').magnificPopup({
                        type: 'image',
                        gallery: {
                          enabled:true
                        },
                        items:GalleryItems,

                     });
                 }

             });

        })( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that @Chris Stage's answer works perfectly, but for some n00bs who try to use the code verbatim may run into issues. I can't just leave a comment or accept the answer so I am posting my revision in hopes that it provides someone else with the correct code.

The one issue I found was that in the .each() function, that you have to target the wrapping a tag's URL to the larger image, not the image's URL itself due to the fact that the one used in the carousel may be a thumbnail or equivalent, and the larger one to the "larger image" to open in a popup may be a separate URL.

```
(function( $ ) {
        'use strict';

         $( window ).load(function(){

             var GalleryItems = [];

             $('.photo-gallery .item a').each(function(i){ //Target your wrapping a tag

                 var src = $(this).attr('href');
                 var theSrc = { 
                    src: src,
                    type: 'image'
                  };
                 GalleryItems.push(theSrc);

             });

             var GalleryItems = GalleryItems.reduce(function(previous, current) {

                  var object = previous.filter(object => object.src === current.src);
                  if (object.length == 0) {
                    previous.push(current);
                  }
                  return previous;
                }, []);

             theGallery();

             function theGallery(){
                 $('.photo-gallery').magnificPopup({ //Target parent carousel container
                    type: 'image',
                    gallery: {
                      enabled:true
                    },
                    items:GalleryItems,
                    removalDelay: 300,
                    mainClass: 'mfp-fade' //Adds magnific's fade effect

                 });
             }

         });

    })( jQuery );
```

This solution worked perfectly with Owl's issue with "cloned" images and thanks to @Chris Stage for coming up with this. His answer should be the "Accepted Answer" but I'd also love an Upvote for the clarification so I can earn some Rep points :)

Comment: Ok, after some fooling around with this code there are still issues with it. If you "Target parent carousel container", this prevents the Owl nav from working properly because it also triggers the popup, and if you add "delegate: 'a'" or "delegate: '.owl-item:not(.cloned) a'", Magnific stops working altogether. I have an issue submitted on the Owl repo here: [Github](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/2428#issue-357251801)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here is a much simpeler solution:

```
$('.owl-item:not(.cloned) * .desert-safari-gallery').magnificPopup(..
```

Change your selector so that it will not be used for children of elements with the 'owl-item cloned' class.

Comment: this should be a go-to solution.

Comment: this is creating an issue. so if I eliminate .cloned items and scroll back to cloned one and click it won't show a magnific pop up because you have eliminated it from script input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little fix.

```js
$('.owl-carousel.with-mfp').each(function () {
    var $mfp = $(this);

    $mfp.on('click', '.owl-item.cloned a', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var self = $(this);

        // Dependency on image positions in owl and on unique a.href attrs
        $mfp.find('.owl-item:not(.cloned) a').each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).attr('href') === self.attr('href')) {
                $mfp.magnificPopup('open', index);
             }
        });
    });

    $mfp.magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        delegate: '.owl-item:not(.cloned) a',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });
```